# CKEDITOR: how to I convert ALL html entities

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

here is the list: http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html
I either want to enable all of them, or disable all of them... (aside from < and > of course)

Is there a way to do this?

there is the config.entities_additional = "", but that is a comma separated list of all the entities you want to store.

preferably, I'd like to disable the entities entirely, but setting config.entities = false; doesn't do anything. o.o

@Cheery's answer solves the situation where the editor uses the config.js file.

however,

```
        CKEDITOR.replace("selected_text_actual", {
            uiColor: "#F5F5F5",
            toolbar: "myToolbar",
            scayt_autoStartup: false,
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
            forceSimpleAmpersand: true,
            height: '170px',
            entities: false,
            basicEntities: false,
            entities_greek: false,
            entities_latin: false,
            toolbarCanCollapse: false,
            resize_enabled: false,
            disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
            removePlugins: 'elementspath',
            editingBlock: false}).setData(text_for_editor);
```

Still has the HTML entities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set all of them to `false`:

```
config.entities  = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
```

Comment: this works for the CKeditor that uses the config file. But what about setting these inline?

Comment: @TheLindyHop It works for any instance of the CKEditor that was started with these options in config. I just tried it and it worked. Check to content of `text_for_editor`.

Comment: I found out it's a problem with having comments in the config. o.o

Comment: Regarding  NullVoxPopuli's comment  " What about setting these online? " : I' ve  just checked with CKEditor 4.5.7 setting them only inline and it works with greek characters, without having set them to false in the ckeditor's config.js file. `code` <script type="text/javascript">
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
        entities: false,
                basicEntities: false,
                basicEntities : false,
                entities_greek: false,
                entities_latin: false,
       } );
      </script> `code`