# Remove / from image source

Tags: php, regex

I'm using CKEDITOR for saving html content. After saving the html to the database, my image source isn't correct for display. For example I save the following html code to database:

```
HELLO WORLD<br \/>
\n\n<hr \/>\n
<img alt=\"\" src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/MM\/uploads\/1370293869_toranj.jpg\"
 style=\"height:244px; width:201px\" \/><br \/>\n
```

The src must be like below:

```
src=\"http://localhost/MM/uploads/1370293869_toranj.jpg\"
```

I want to remove `\` from src starting from `http` to end of src url.

**UPDATE:**

after any try with `str_replace` and `preg_replace` i can use this below code for remove `\` from src and replace `/` width `\` for create correct image src to displage

```
echo str_replace('\\','/', preg_replace('/\/+/i', '', $html));
```

Comment: Before pressing the `submit` button, can you review your question ? There are so much typos which is not really "cool".

Comment: sending data and save to database can successfull insert. i want to replace after fetch from database

Comment: You should not be saving escaped sequences in your database in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using str_replace() combined with preg_match()?

```
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $imagetag, $array ) ;
str_replace('\\"','"', $array[1] ) ; //not tested
```

mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

I don't know actually why and how you store the escaped sequences, but maybe this is also a helpful function for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Maybe interesting too: [CKEditor is escaping html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700383/ckeditor-escaping-html-elements)

Comment: because i cant use preg_replace and str_replace for src

Comment: @mahdipishguy that doesn't make sense at all. You want to remove something, you don't want to match.

Comment: @abimelex, my correct result is: `echo str_replace('\\','/', preg_replace('/\/+/i', '', $html));`

Comment: super. Just for interest, did you also tried htmlspecialchars-decode() or to setup the editor like mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507250/ckeditor-how-to-i-convert-all-html-entities/9509108#9509108